# Корректно ли использовать наречие "впрямую"?

Tags: стилистика

Корректно ли использовать наречие "впрямую" в предложении: статья 4 в отличие от статьи 38 УПК впрямую не наделяет дознавателя правом давать органу дознания обязательные для исполнения письменные поручения о производстве отдельных следственных действий?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос оказался неожиданно сложным...
"Впрямую" носит разговорный характер и оно не совсем соответствует смыслу. 
"Напрямую" тут бы было ближе, но оно тоже не совсем точно.
Можно, конечно, просто "прямо", но тут на смысл надо будет посмотреть "причастным" к этой терминологии. Для простых смертных, наверное, все-таки надо заменить на "непосредственно".

Comment: ***Непосредственно*** - да, мне нравится такой вариант. А чем ***напрямую*** не понравилось?

Comment: Писал же. "Напрямую" у Кузнецова даётся с той же пометой разг., что и "впрямую". И значение у него несколько другое.

Answer (score 0):

Не наделяет (*как?*) впрямую.

Возможно Вам следует использовать наречие "напрямую". Оно более литературное на мой взгляд.

Comment: По БТС Кузнецова "напрямую" даётся с той же пометой "разг."  
Но тут есть ещё и проблема смысла. Напрямую - не стольео "прямого действия", что явно хочет автор, а "без посредников", чего он явно не хочет.